# ExoPlayer Cant Play some audio streams

Tags: android, audio, stream, audio-streaming, exoplayer

i am newbie here. i am developing a android app to listen to online radio stations.

problem i am getting here is ExoPlayer(2.9.2) can or cant play some streams of same type of different bitrates.

For Example

These mpga streams

```
http://108.61.34.50:7130/              ---> 96kbs ===> Playable
http://s3.voscast.com:8408             ---> 64kbs ===> Not Playable
http://220.247.227.20:8000/citystream  ---> 128kbs ===> Not Playable
```

i used vlc codec window to get this information, and those 3 streams share same values other than bitrate.

i am using ExtractorMediaSource

```
    songs.add(Uri.parse("http://220.247.227.20:8000/citystream"));//City

    player= ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,
            new DefaultTrackSelector());

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "AudioApp"));

    ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();
    for (Uri temp : songs)
    {
        BaseMediaSource mediaSourse=
                new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(temp);
        concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSourse);
    }

    player.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Hope anyone can help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing various different streams, i realized that this is a device specific error.
Huawei Y5 2017

the other phone's that i tested work pretty well and i ended up submiting issue to ExpoPlayer team on github without knowing this is device specific issue.
Here it is

[Why does ExoPlayer cant play some of the streams of same type with different bitrates ?](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5259)